# What do I use in Discord.py when I am not using Cogs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am making a ticket bot for my Discord server so users can ask staff questions. And I am doing this by following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMnBz_vSE_4). The person in the video uses Cogs but I am not planning on doing so since the bot only does tickets. A bit further in the video when he start actually creating the ticket there is a part where he users `@commands.Cogs.listener()` but since I am not planning on using Cogs I don't know what I should put there instead.

I have tried `@bot.listener()` but that gave me the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'listener'`

I have also tried `@bot.Cogs.listener` but that also did not work, and it gave me almost the same error.

`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'Cogs'`

**So my question is, what do I put in instead?**

Here is my code so you can see what I need to do.

```
@bot.Cogs.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.member.id != bot.used.id:
    with open('ticket.json', 'r') as file:
      ticket_data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: It's the first thing in the docs... Have you tried `@bot.event`? You can also use `@bot.listen()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`bot.add_listener`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_listener) or [`@bot.listen`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.listen)/[`@bot.event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event) instead.